# No data in CDS following the import of my solution

Tags: powerapps, common-data-service, dataverse

I just finished the import of my solution into a new environment. Even though I thought I had selected everything from CDS, it would seem that the data didn't follow (the table is there, however).

Did I miss something? Or is this intentional? I see the message "No data available" when I navigate to my model driven power app.

These are the options I selected when I added the table to my solution:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions don't include data.

They only contain the configuration.

If you need to include data look at the [Configuration Migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/manage-configuration-data) tool from Microsoft or the [Solution Packager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/compress-extract-solution-file-solutionpackager)

Comment: Thanks. I think I had assumed too many things from the Power Platform. I'm missing my old DevOps/CI processes more and more (and having access to server side code, code repos and database servers).

Comment: @TekiusFanatikus You can build a DevOps pipeline with the Power Platform. Check out SPKL form Scott Durow and Power Devops Tools from Wael Hamze. Scott also has a good course getting all of it set up.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check those out.